# How does firebase passwordless authentication work with dynamic link for a flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When I click on verification link from my email , it opens my app running in background but didChangeAppLifecycleState method returns data as null and deepLink as set in firebase instead of the whole emailLink from my email, resulting in SignInWithEmailAndLink to fail as its supposed to match email address entered in widget from the link recieved.

Here's the code taken from this article https://medium.com/firebase-developers/dive-into-firebase-auth-on-flutter-email-and-link-sign-in-e51603eb08f8 :-

1.didChangeAppLifecycleState method

```dart
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    if( data?.link != null ) {
      handleLink(data?.link);
    }
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          final Uri deepLink `enter code here`= dynamicLink?.link;
          handleLink(deepLink);
        }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });
  }
}
```

2. handleLink method

```dart
void handleLink(Uri link) async {
  if (link != null) {
    final User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndLink(
      email: _userEmail,
      link: link.toString(),
    ))
        .user;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _userID = user.uid;
        _success = true;
    });
    } else {
    setState(() {
        _success = false;
      });
    }
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _success = false;
    });
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

3. main method (initializing firebase)

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Note: - Deeplink is a concept still new to me in flutter, so I have set it randomly in firebase. My register page has a WidgetsBindingObserver to help resume app lifecycle state. My signup and sign in code is in an email widget and I'm not using forms to validate my textfields.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that after you signin with email link the firebase instance has been not updated before checking auth.SigninWithEMailLink() you need to  update it in firebase instance like this

```
  var user= await auth.currentUser();
              await user.reload();
              user=await auth.currentUser();
```

if still you are facing problem please provide some more  code to let me understand your issue properly

Comment: My understanding is I cannot get a currentUser until the user gets registered upon signing up ( I can't see the user in firebase as well). I have provided the code with more information in details, let me know if you would like to know anything more.